# Generate JAX-RS server from swagger editor not working

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, apache-tomee

I'm trying to use swagger editor (http://editor.swagger.io/#/) to generate JAX-RS server from the documentation.

I choose Generate Server -> JAX-RS and tried to run the code on Apache
TomEE 1.7.4 and got the following error:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle
>   transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>   in state [STARTING_PREP]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:401)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1537)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1518)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:762)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1982)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:663)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:622)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:176)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:370)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:58)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: paste complete error stacktrace

Comment: @GautamSavaliya Added, you can also generate the code from http://editor.swagger.io/#/ and see if you can run it. Thanks!

Comment: I could run the jaxrs server stub with `mvn jetty:run`. The issue you encountered may be specified to Apache TomEE

Answer (score 0):

issue is "JAX-RS" on swagger editor doesn't mean "JAX-RS" but "jersey". In TomEE JAX-RS is provided so you can remove almost all dependencies from the pom.

Swagger also have "CXF" flavor of JAX-RS server which would fit better TomEE default stack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have correctly building your WAR package?

To run on TomEE, you have to update the pom.xml by changing the packaging as follow:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then for running with maven you can add the tomee-maven-plugin (pom.xml):

```
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <tomeeVersion>1.7.4</tomeeVersion>
    <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Finally :

```
mvn clean package
mvn tomee:run
```

And *Voilà*

> http://localhost:8080/swagger-jaxrs-server-1.0.0/ works!